# Wrong Qt lib linked

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qt5

On Ubuntu 18.04 I have multiple Qt versions installed.

Default one is selected by QT_SELECT is Qt5.5.1.

I want to build my project with custom one Qt5.12.8 and do `export QT_SELECT=qt5.12`.

But in the end I have binary which tells me that it still points to few default libs of Qt.

How could this happen?

EDIT:
I see that Qt5Svg lib is missing in my Qt 5.12 build, but Qt5OpenGL is present.

ldd output:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post error text as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was my project had in dependencies other Qt-based lib which was build with Qt5.5. So in the end it forced this version of few Qt modules to be linked to main project.